# Move the Marker on Google Maps like Uber iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to develop an application based on Uber and Ola like concept. So for this I need to integrate the Google Maps to user tracking location on iOS. So please tell me how to achieve the Moving marker (car) animation in iOS using Google Maps.

Answer (score 5):

I've same app, where I need to show Driver's location to customer for live tracking. Following things are required.

1. Constant Getting driver's new location.
2. Update driver's marker with animation.

Here is my code for update marker with animation.

```
func setDriversNewLocation(location:CLLocation) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(timer.timeInterval)
    driverMarker.position = location.coordinate
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

where `timer.timeInterval` is same as I'm calling API to get new location for Driver. i.e. 5 seconds.
**--EDIT--**
Here I've wrote code for your requirement. I'm getting user's location and based on that updating marker.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 22.2729, longitude: 70.7584, zoom: 18.0)
mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
mapView.delegate = self
view = mapView

myMarker = GMSMarker()
myMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 22.2729, longitude: 70.7584)
myMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
myMarker.title = "Sydney"
myMarker.snippet = "Australia"
myMarker.map = mapView
myMarker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "car")
...
extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.2)
        myMarker.position = locationManager!.location!.coordinate
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        lastUserBearing = newHeading.trueHeading
        myMarker.rotation = lastUserBearing! - (lastMapBearing ?? 0)
    }
}

extension ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        lastMapBearing = position.bearing
        myMarker.rotation = (lastUserBearing ?? 0) - lastMapBearing!
    }
}
```

Here I'm getting current user's location. But instead of that as per your requirement you can change latitude, longitude and rotationAngle as per your requirement.

Comment: hi thanks for reply

Comment: and this is my code for getting latitude and longitude.  let dice = pointsArray as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                        let latitudeString = dice["latitude"] as? NSString
                        let longitudeString = dice["longitude"] as? NSString
                        let speedString = dice["speed"] as? String
                        let bearingString = dice["bearing"] as? String.

Comment: can you send  me sample code of your project to my mail.

Comment: Actually I'm not using speed and bearing property for updating with animation.

Comment: @JohnJS , [Here](http://dpaste.com/2M6ZC0T) is my sample code.

Comment: ok thank you for sharing file. and how you are showing car moment. how you are updates coordinates accordingly

Comment: Actually we've round marker for driver which have driver's icon. So, there is not head or tails to be manage for marker.

Comment: ok how you are updating old coordinates with new coordinates.

Comment: the code which I posted as answer

Comment: @JohnJS , Take look on my edited answer. May be you can get more idea.

Comment: @MrugeshTank Jordar bhai

Comment: ok thq let me try

Comment: @MrugeshTank Can you please share your sample code?

Comment: @KhushbuDesai about which part exactly?

Comment: @Mrugesh tank can u please share code with me both user side and driver side at my mail barhardik@gmail.com

Comment: @Mrugesh Tank How can we achieve this for multiple cars moving around

Comment: Then it'll be array of myMarker and rotate each object of array.

Answer (score 0):

Use CATransaction :

```
let animationDuration = 4.0 // in seconds

CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setValue(NSNumber(value: animationDuration as Float), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)

// set marker properties to animate here
marker.position = position.coordinate
marker.rotation = position.course

CATransaction.commit()
```